# how to concact more than two requirements at a time

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

hi all i have written a logic based on a requirement concact more than two data at a time in my xslt code but i m not reaching my expected output can any one give some suggestions

here is my xml

```
         <Swift>
            <block4>
                  <tag>
            <name>50K</name>
            <value>
                0101/0457887750
                SAMAROCA
                MENENDEZ Y PELAYO
            </value>
        </tag>
            </block4>
      </Swift>
```

i have written an xslt here :

```
<xsl:template  match="swift/message/block4/tag [name='50K']">       
    <xsl:variable name ="del50k" select ="(translate(substring-after(value,'&#13;'),'&#13;','~'))"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(value, 1, 5), ',',substring(substring-before(value,'&#13;'),6), ',',$del50k)" /> 
</xsl:template>
```

is that way doing is correct or not ? can any one help

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

**0101/,0457887750,SAMAROCA~MENENDEZ Y PELAYO**

Comment: `match="swift/message/block4/tag [name='50K']/value` is not going to match anything. Your input does not contain a `message` element.

Comment: @empo no i have given like this >> match="swift/message/block4/tag [name='50K']

Comment: Yes, but your XML doesn't contain any element called `message`. Also, the `Swift` element is capitalized; XML is case sensitive, this makes a difference. I'd also suggest you describe what output you're currently getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm giving you a full working example based on your input. A few notes:

- Use `normalize-space()` and split the string by space.
- Just play with `substring-before` and `substring-after`.
- make sure to use `xsl:strip-space`.

---

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    >
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="space" select="'&#x20;'"/>

    <xsl:template match="block4/tag[name='50K']">
        <xsl:variable name="value" select="normalize-space(value)"/>

        <xsl:variable name="code" select="substring-before($value,$space)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="string1" select="concat(
            substring-before($code,'/'),
            '/,',
            substring-after($code,'/'))"/>
        <xsl:variable name="string2" select="substring-before(
            substring-after($value,$space),
            $space)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="string3" select="substring-after(
            substring-after($value,$space),
            $space)"/>

        <xsl:value-of select="concat($string1,',',$string2,'~',$string3)"/>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="name|value"/>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: awesome code simple way to understand ...!!! but really i don't what i made a mistake in my logic

Comment: Among other things above commented, `translate()` is not going to work well with special characters, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Your biggest problem is that `value` is you context node (defined in your template's `match` attribute), but you're referring to `value` in your XPath. This will look for a `value` node within the `value` node, which is obviously wrong.

In your `<xsl:variable>` and `<xsl:value-of>` statements, change refences to `value` to `.`, to refer to the current node instead.

I think that's probably not the only issue, but given that your template isn't going to match anything in that document anyway, it's difficult to derive where else it could be going wrong. One possible additional problem is that your `substring-before(value,'&#13;')` predicate within your `<xsl:value-of>` isn't going to return anything with the formatting given, as there's a newline before the `0101/etc..`. Now I think about it, that's also going to be issue in the `substring-after` in the previous line. That's very dependent on how it's actually formatted though, but from what you've given here, it is a problem.